# insert query in public function

Tags: php

I want to write two insert queries in single class function.Anybody knows please help me. Here is my code:

```
public function insertlocation($data) {
    $this->db->insert ( 'locations', array (
            'subscriber_id' => Session::get ( 'subId' ),
            'location_name' => $data ['location_name'],
            'location_ip' => $data ['location_ip'],
            'working_hours_start' => date ( 'H:i:s', strtotime ( $data ['w_time_start'] ) ),
            'working_hours_end' => date ( 'H:i:s', strtotime ( $data ['w_time_end'] ) ),
            'time_zone' => $data ['time_zone'],
            'ip_lock' => $data ['select_ip_lock'],
            'time_lock' => $data ['select_time_lock'],
            'created' => date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
            'status' => $data ['status'],
            'currency_id' => $data ['currency'],
            'monthly_target' => $data ['target'] 
    ) );
    return $this->db->lastInsertId ();

    $this->db->insert ( 'year_target', array (
            'location_ip' => $data ['location_ip'],
            'year' => $data ['year'],
            'monthly_target' => $data ['target'] 
    )
     );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the return in the middle of the function and return both insert ids at the end (if you need them).

```
public function insertlocation($data) {
    $this->db->insert ( 'locations', array (
            'subscriber_id' => Session::get ( 'subId' ),
            'location_name' => $data ['location_name'],
            'location_ip' => $data ['location_ip'],
            'working_hours_start' => date ( 'H:i:s', strtotime ( $data ['w_time_start'] ) ),
            'working_hours_end' => date ( 'H:i:s', strtotime ( $data ['w_time_end'] ) ),
            'time_zone' => $data ['time_zone'],
            'ip_lock' => $data ['select_ip_lock'],
            'time_lock' => $data ['select_time_lock'],
            'created' => date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
            'status' => $data ['status'],
            'currency_id' => $data ['currency'],
            'monthly_target' => $data ['target'] 
    ) );

    $return_value[] = $this->db->lastInsertId ();

    $this->db->insert ( 'year_target', array (
            'location_ip' => $data ['location_ip'],
            'year' => $data ['year'],
            'monthly_target' => $data ['target'] 
    ));

    $return_value[] = $this->db->lastInsertId ();

    return $return_value;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But the values are inserting only in locations table not in year_target table.

Comment: What if you switch the order or don't insert anything into `locations` at all? Please try to extract a minimal example, I'm pretty sure you're not telling the whole story and that that's a key point in understanding what is going on.

Comment: I need to insert values in two tables. year column should be insert into year_target table and not in locations table. Thats why i have created year_target table.  @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: Please study the posting guidelines, in particular the part concerning the creation of a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks!! I have found the issue.